# SQL group records but show not null in the group

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables TabA, TabB
I am interested in joining them together  so that result has the same amount of records as TabA, and it joins only non NULL values from TabB. That being said

```
TabA
field1 field2
1      valone
1      valtwo
2      valone
3      valone

TabB
field3 field4, field5
1      NULL    test3
1      test1   NULL
2      test2   NULL
```

The result that I am trying to get is:

```
field1 field2 field4 field5
1      valone test1  test3
1      valtwo test1  test3
2      valone test2  NULL
3      valone NULL   NULL
```

Thus far I have

```
SELECT TabA.field1, TabA.field2, TabA.field4
FROM TabA
LEFT JOIN TabB ON TabA.field1 = TabB.field3
```

However this does not take into account the fact I want to return same amount of rows as in TabA.

Comment: What have you tried?  Use an `outer join` and `not null` to filter out the records from `tabb` that you do no want to view...

Comment: Your edits have changed the solution -- now you need to use `conditional aggregation` (or additional `joins`).  What if multiple records exist in `tabb` that aren't `null`?

Comment: The query with the left join should do exactly that. what results are you getting?

Comment: Yes i'm expecting to see many missing values in tabb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 common approaches to your problem.  One is to use multiple `outer joins`:

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.field4, b2.field5
from TabA a
    left join TabB b on a.field1 = b.field3 and b.field4 is not null
    left join TabB b2 on a.field1 = b2.field3 and b2.field5 is not null
```

This however could return multiple results if `TabB` has multiple records where `field4` or `field5` are not null per `field3`.

---

To eliminate duplicates, another option is to use `conditional aggregation`.

```
select a.field1, a.field2,
       max(case when b.field4 is not null then b.field4 end) field4,
       max(case when b.field5 is not null then b.field5 end) field5
from TabA a
     left join TabB b on a.field1 = b.field3
group by a.field1, a.field2
```

If multiple records exist, this will only return a single row per record in `TabA`, but `field4` and/or `field5` might not be what you want.  Depends on your desired results at that point.

If duplicates aren't an issue, then both solutions should produce your desired results.

Comment: you are right that my initial description of the problem was over simplified, that is is why I had to update it.